# Horizontal navigation in long lines

Tags: navigation, vim

How can I do the following:

1. shift faster to the right, something like `zw` (analogy to `zl` but jump on words)
2. shift only the one long line where is the cursor. The rest of the file will remain in its position

I have `.vimrc` settings `set nowrap`. That's because the code looks nicer than wrapped lines. But there is a problem with horizontal navigation.

I noticed that `zl` (don't confuse l (L) with 1) shortcut which shifts to the right (`zh` to the left).

Comment: I expect you've seen zL (shift half a screen-width to the right), and 6zl (shift 6 characters to the right).  For your second question, I don't know how to adjust the view of individual lines.

Comment: @neillb Thanks zL and zH is great. Second question is more difficult.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Did you try [`:help scroll-horizontal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-horizontal)?

You could use a mapping to scroll, for example, 20 characters to the left or to the right:

```
map <C-L> 20zl " Scroll 20 characters to the right
map <C-H> 20zh " Scroll 20 characters to the left
```

Without applying a mapping, you could use `zL` to move the view a half screenwidth to the right and `zH` to do it to the left.

Regarding the second part of your question: I don't think that this is possible. You could yank the whole line, paste it into a second (scratch) buffer and scroll there. This would work as long as you're just reading the lines. Problems will arise as soon as you want to change something. But it's quite cumbersome...

Comment: Second buffer is good idea. And achieves what I want, I used `:sp` for this.

Comment: `set nowrap` is required

Comment: `zL` and `zH` are not working for me. what could be going on?

Comment: @nilon Your cursor needs to be on a "long" line.

Answer (score 24):

adding to other answers also pay attention to `ze` and `zs`, meaning: move screen to the left/right of the cursor

below I paste my mnemonic for scrolling 
also look at the position of `h` and `l` (and `t` and `b`) on the keyboard to remember where the screen is moving

```
+-------------------------------+
^                               |
|c-e (keep cursor)              |
|H(igh)             zt (top)    |
|                   ^           |
|           ze      |      zs   |
|M(iddle)  zh/zH <--zz--> zl/zL |
|                   |           |
|                   v           |
|L(ow)              zb (bottom) |
|c-y (keep cursor)              |
v                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

Use shift + scrolling keys to move faster through text

Comment: Isn't this the equivalent of using w and b?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's another way of horizontal and vertical navigation in vi/vim editor.

Answer (score 7):

For the first part of your question, as in the comments, `zL` and `zH` are perfect, so I'll add this here.

```
zL          Move the view on the text half a screenwidth to the
            right, thus scroll the text half a screenwidth to the
            left.  This only works when 'wrap' is off.

zH          Move the view on the text half a screenwidth to the
            left, thus scroll the text half a screenwidth to the
            right.  This only works when 'wrap' is off.
```

Answer (score 6):

For a more comfortable scrolling, similar to the scrolling mode triggered by ctrl-x,ctrl-e or ctrl-x,ctrl-y in insert mode, here is what I added in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> zh :call HorizontalScrollMode('h')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> zl :call HorizontalScrollMode('l')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> zH :call HorizontalScrollMode('H')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> zL :call HorizontalScrollMode('L')<CR>

function! HorizontalScrollMode( call_char )
    if &wrap
        return
    endif

    echohl Title
    let typed_char = a:call_char
    while index( [ 'h', 'l', 'H', 'L' ], typed_char ) != -1
        execute 'normal! z'.typed_char
        redraws
        echon '-- Horizontal scrolling mode (h/l/H/L)'
        let typed_char = nr2char(getchar())
    endwhile
    echohl None | echo '' | redraws
endfunction
```

This way, you can scroll smoothly (with h or l) or rapidly (with H or L) at your convenience without pressing z again and again each time. You just press z once in order to trigger the "horizontal scrolling mode", which stop as soon as you press any other key.

Answer (score -1):

Use `w` to scroll forward and `b` to scroll backward. This is probably the easiest way.

Comment: These do not scroll the screen, if your cursor is not on the line you want to scroll, you will get unexpected results. Also, if you're on the last word of the line it's fairly possible vIm will skip to the start of the next line, making it impossible to read.

Not great if you use :set ve=all