# How is vim horrizontal scroll enabled for mouse use?

Tags: vim, scroll

It seems that it is possible to use mouse to scroll text horizontal, just like it is possible to scroll vertical up and down.

Can somebody explain how I setup vim 7.4 to be-able to use horizontal scroll with mouse - something like this < Ctrl key > < mousewheel up/down >

Comment: It seems to depend on your environment (GUI or not, which GUI, which term...). A couple links: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989739/horizontal-navigation-in-long-lines) and also [`:help scroll-mouse-wheel`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-mouse-wheel)

Comment: :set nowrap
:set guioptions+=b
these two settings will enable a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the window

Comment: yes I looked at these explanations, however I do not really see how I can map ctrl key + wheel up to a scroll right

Comment: if you keep the mouse point over the horizontal scroll bar and scrolling up and down will move the horizontal scroll bar left and right.

Comment: it seems your setup is different - this does not work for me