# How to enable horizontal scroll on vim with trackpad/mouse?

Tags: macos, vim

How to enable horizontal scroll on vim using the trackpad on macOS (I guess is the same as mouse on other OS)?

I tried

```
:set sidescrool=1
```

I noticed the window moves if I hit `z` left or `z` right.

I noticed macvim has it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal navigation in long lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989739/horizontal-navigation-in-long-lines)

Comment: Changed title, now is not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling inside Vim in Mac's Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727261/scrolling-inside-vim-in-macs-terminal)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this, it may work. Open system Preferences (under the apple menu) and then select general. About half way down that window are options related to the scroll bars. Select one of these and see if it works.